# Walletconnect not firing App in mobile but redirect

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, ethers.js, wallet-connect

i can't figured out why when i call a method with provider, walletconnect keeps redirecting me in https://link.trustwallet.com instead of open me the app to approve the transaction. I've wrote the code for metamask and walletconnect and i used ethersjs to handle the provider.

Here's code for connection

```
 const getBlockchain = (typew) =>
  new Promise(async (resolve) => {
    var provider;
    if(typew == "metamask"){
      /* @ts-ignore */
      if(window.ethereum) {
        /* @ts-ignore */
        await window.ethereum.enable();
        /* @ts-ignore */
        provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
      }
    }
      
    if(typew == "walletconnect"){
        providerEth = new WalletConnectProvider({
          chainId: 56,
          rpc: {
            56: "https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org",
          }
        });

        await providerEth.enable();
        provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(providerEth); 

        provider.off("disconnect");
        provider.on("disconnect", () => {
          closeBlockhain();
        })
    }
    
    
    if(provider !== undefined){
      const signer = provider.getSigner();
      /* @ts-ignore */
      const signerAddress:any = await signer.getAddress();

      const contract = new Contract(
        Contract.networks[56].address,
        Contract.abi,
        signer
      );

      const contract_two = new Contract(
        Contract_two.networks[56].address,
        Contract_two.abi,
        signer
      );

      configConnections = {
        connected: true,
        provider,
        contract,
        contract_two,
        signerAddress: signerAddress
      }

      resolve(configConnections);
    }
  
  resolve(configConnections);
 });
```

Here's the code for method

```
let test = await configConnections.contract.awardItem(ethers.utils.formatBytes32String("1"),res.data.hash);
```

Can't explain to myself why if i open the app on mobile and try to call method, the browser redirects me on other page not on the TrustWallet or Metamask App.

Thank you.

Comment: I've tried to remove the axios before the contract call and it worked. I can't figured out why if i put a setTimeout before or i wait for a response, the app redirects me. 

All Code:
`if(configConnections.connected){
   setDisabled(true);
   const res = await axios.post(API_ENDPOINTS.ORIGINAL+API_ENDPOINTS.CREATE, { values,image });
   if(res.data !== false){
    let takeOn = await configConnections.contract.awardItem(ethers.utils.formatBytes32String("1"),res.data.hash);
    await takeOn.wait().then(function(x) {}) } }`